# ¿Cómo desproteger una pestaña de excel protegida con contraseña?

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo un Excel antiguo que en su día fue protegido con clave para la hoja, de manera que no se puede modificar el ancho de columnas ni introducir nuevos gráficos. Además las fórmulas no aparecen en la barra de fórmulas.

Ahora es necesario modificarlo pero no tengo la clave de protección.

¿Sabe alguien algún método que pueda utilizar para desbloquear la hoja?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado. He seguido buscando hasta encontrar un código en VBA que hace exactamente eso. No recupera la clave original pero si una equivalente.

<sub>PEGAR EL SIGUIENTE SCRIPT EN EL CODIGO DE LA HOJA DESEADA</sub>

```
Sub SacaClaves()
    Dim Contraseña As String
    Dim i01 As Integer, i02 As Integer, i03 As Integer
    Dim i04 As Integer, i05 As Integer, i06 As Integer
    Dim i07 As Integer, i08 As Integer, i09 As Integer
    Dim i10 As Integer, i11 As Integer, i12 As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    For i01 = 65 To 66: For i02 = 65 To 66: For i03 = 65 To 66
    For i04 = 65 To 66: For i05 = 65 To 66: For i06 = 65 To 66
    For i07 = 65 To 66: For i08 = 65 To 66: For i09 = 65 To 66
    For i10 = 65 To 66: For i11 = 65 To 66: For i12 = 32 To 126
        Contraseña = Chr(i01) & Chr(i02) & Chr(i03) & Chr(i04) & Chr(i05) & Chr(i06) & Chr(i07) & Chr(i08) & Chr(i09) & Chr(i10) & Chr(i11) & Chr(i12)
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Contraseña
        If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = False Then
            Debug.Print Contraseña
            MsgBox "La contraseña encontrada es " & Contraseña
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next: Next: Next
    Next: Next: Next
    Next: Next: Next
    Next: Next: Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Me alegra que encontraras solucion pero, has tardado 3 min en encontrarla tras hacr la pregunta. La proxima vez emplea mas tiempo en buscar la solucion **antes** de publicar la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Disculpa, fallo mío. Perdí la paciencia. Ha sido raro XD porque me he pasado más de una hora buscando y hasta que no he hecho la pregunta no se me ha ocurrido como buscarlo en google XD

Comment: Nada, no te disculples. Estas cosas pasan. Tras perder la paciencia, haces un descanso y mas tarde vuelves a intentarlo. Puede que tengas otro punto de vista como te pasó tras publicar la pregunta. [Esta foto](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/71/0c/35/710c35a1da80c5e98d7cc5bc91d903dc.jpg) lo representa muy bien